# Three <spans> to stay on one line and expand downwards no matter what content

Tags: html, styling

So I've this problem with an addon for wordpress that don't seem to be supported but is something I'd like to use anyway.

Name of the addon is **VS Restaurant Menu** (Visual Composer).

The problem I'm facing is maybe something that has an easy solution but I don't have the skill to make it happen, and don't really know how to explain it best.

Thank you all in advance!

**Problem**
So the addon make it possible to easy place menu-items in Visual Composer, but when the dish title is to long it pushes down the price, and I don't want that.

The addon is made in  Span1, Span2 and Span 3.

Span 1 : Number
Span 2 : Dish Title
Span 3 : Price

This is how the spans look on the site:

[image]

**What I'm looking for**
I want the spans to stay on the same line and grow downwards instead of pushing down the next span.

I've tried to look for a solution with all kinds of css, but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description doesn't contain any code, which really isn't the way you should ask a question here, but here is a general approach:

Apply `width` settings in percent to the spans (like 10% / 75% / 10%), make them `display: inline-block` and add `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: I know, cause i didn't create the code. 
Is percentage the way to go? Is the span growing with the content if floated then?

Comment: well, but without the code you won't be able get a detailed answer.

Comment: I understand, but your answer was really good anyways. I made a solution with it that worked good in all viewports. So thank you very much!

If i find more problems I'll make sure to add the code.